# Implementing backward-convolution in CNN for multi-channel data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, correlation, convolution

I have been trying to get a deeper understanding of convolutional operation as I am implementing a convolutional neural network. But I am stuck while trying to calculate the backward pass or deconvolution.

Lets say the input is a 3 dimensional RGB image with dimension `3x7x7` The filter has the dimension `3x3x3`. On convolving with stride set to 2 we will get an output of dimension `3x3`.

Now here is my problem. I have read that deconvolution is the convolution of the output with flipped kernel. But on flipping the kernel, it will still be of dimension `3x3x3` and output is of dimension `3x3` which . The input was of dimension `3x7x7` . So, how is deconvolution calculated ?

Comment: Are you talking about 2D or 3D convolution? What do you mean by `3x3x3` filter shape?

Comment: @maxim I am talking about 3D convolution thats why the filter is 3D

Comment: @Maxim I believe he means 2D color image, the 3 is for the 3 channels

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic) is a nice visualisation how convolution and deconvolution (transposed convolution). The white pieces are simply zeros.

Comment: The article is great but I still don't understand how deconvolution works for 3D data as the resultant of convolution is 2D but the filter itself is 3D.

Comment: A color image has 3 channels, red, green and blue. So a 7x7x3 image means its 3 separate 7x7 maps that record the intensities of each of the RGB colors.